# how to extract information from a ipv6 packet

Tags: sockets, tcp, ipv6, ipv4, packet-sniffers

I am writing my own packet sniffer using python sockets by retrieving the
packet information such as source ip, source port, destination ip,
destion port, TTL, Flags (SYN, ACK, FIN, RST, PSH, URG) etc.

For IPv4, I am able to unpack the packet based on the respective positions, and the result is similar to what I see with tshark. See code below:

```
IPv4_UNPACK_PATTERN = '!BBHHHBBH4s4s'
IPv6_UNPACK_PATTERN = '!4sHBB16s16s'

IPv4_HDR_LEN = 20
IPv6_HDR_LEN = 40
TCP_HDR_LEN = 20
ETH_HDR_LEN = 14

# IP ATTRIBUTES
IP_VERSION_POS = 0
IP_TOS_POS = 1
IP_LENGTH_POS = 2
IP_IDENTIFICATION_POS = 3
IP_FRAGMENT_OFFSET_POS = 4
IP_TTL_POS = 5
IP_PROTOCOL_POS = 6
IP_HDR_CHCKSUM_POS = 7
IP_SRC_ADDR_POS = 8
IP_DST_ADDR_POS = 9

TCP_FLAG_POS = 5
TCP_WINDOW_POS = 6

# main program:
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))
packet = s.recvfrom(SOCKET_BUFF_SIZE)
pkt_type = extract_type(packet)
ip_header(packet, pkt_type)

# this function extracts the information from pkt
def ip_header(pkt, pkt_type):
if pkt_type=='ipv4':
    data = unpack(IPv4_UNPACK_PATTERN, pkt[ETH_HDR_LEN:ETH_HDR_LEN + IPv4_HDR_LEN])
    version = data[IP_VERSION_POS]
    total_length = data[IP_LENGTH_POS]
    ttl = data[IP_TTL_POS]
    protocol = data[IP_PROTOCOL_POS]
    ip_header = (version & 0xF) * 4
    start_pos = ETH_HDR_LEN + IPv4_HDR_LEN
    # Unpacking TCP
    tcp_obj = unpack(TCP_UNPACK_PATTERN, data[start_pos:start_pos + TCP_HDR_LEN])
    tcp_flag = tcp_obj[TCP_FLAG_POS]
    window = str(tcp_obj[TCP_WINDOW_POS])
else:  # ipv6
    data = unpack(IPv6_UNPACK_PATTERN, pkt[ETH_HDR_LEN:ETH_HDR_LEN + IPv6_HDR_LEN])
    # what bit positions to be used here for ipv6?
```

But for the IPv6 packet, I do not know the correct bit positions for ipv6 fields.

Can anybody point me to the document which describes the bit positions for ipv6 packets for the following fields:

1. version
2. ip total length
3. TTL
4. protocol
5. ip header
6. TCP flags
7. Window size
8. Don't fragment bit
9. More fragment bit

Comment: IP packets (either IPv4 or IPv6) do not have TCP information in the packet headers. TCP _may or may not_ be in the packet payload. You need to study IPv6 a bit more. There is no DF or more fragments because routers are not allowed to fragment IPv6 packets. There are also extension headers that may be part of the packet, and each has its own format.

Comment: [RFC 8200](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8200) describes IPv6, you can work from there on to TCP etc.